# How to set the cursor in kEventControlSetCursor?

Tags: macos, cursor, macos-carbon

I want to be able to change the appearance of the mouse cursor as it moves over various hot spots in my view's and it seems to me that I should be doing that in the kEventControlSetCursor handler (which I can get). The function "SetCursor" is deprecated, which leads to the question, what do I call to actually change the cursor?

And is there some standard list of cursors I can use? Things like horizontal and vertical arrows? I beam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetThemeCursor` or `SetAnimatedThemeCursor`, which are both part of the Appearance Manager.

> And is there some standard list of cursors I can use? Things like horizontal and vertical arrows? I beam?

The standard cursors, including those, are *all* you can use in the Appearance Manager; it provides no way to set a custom cursor.

The modern replacement for all three functions is Cocoa's NSCursor, which provides standard cursors and supports custom cursors.

Comment: And they couldn't just say that in the documentation for SetCursor could they :( Thanks... works perfectly.